# in git, merge changes from older file to newer file within same repo

Tags: git, github

Our repo has two directories that contain code for the same module.  We need to merge the two versions together.  One version is older and has history we want to retain.  The other version is newer and also has history we want to retain.

Older version is at location `top/theModule`

Newer version is at location `top/project/subProject/theModule`

Target folder is at location `top/project/theModule`

How do I merge the newer code on top of the older code and have everything end up in the target folder?  `cherry-pick` seemed like the right solution but I couldn't figure out how to specify locations within the repo.  The `patch` command also looked promising but again, there isn't a way to specify filesystem targets.

Comment: Do you have a base version - a version that is a common ancestor to both paths?  Ideally it would be the older version but without your history.

Comment: I think the answer is yes, if by base version you mean a version that I could produce by checking out the initial commit of the 'older version' that's currently at location `top/theModule`.  In this case, it seems like `git merge-file` would be the solution?

Comment: That or manually do "git cat-file -p" pr "git show SHA:FILE" to get the file contents redirected to temp files and then pass them directly to your mergetool.  Either should work.

Comment: Tried the `git merge-file` method but history does not seem to be preserved.  The end result is not showing the 12 commits that belong to the original base file (`top/theModule/basefile.c`).  The newer version has 13 commits.  I would expect there to be a total of 25 commits shown by `git log` after the operation is complete.  Maybe `merge-file` doesn't preserve history, in which case this solution won't work for me.

Comment: As best as I know there is no way to preserve history of a single file represented by 2 different files in the same commits.  You could always pop out a branch is old history, replay the changes on that for the old version, and then merge

Comment: Could you provide a quick example given the folders above and a `master` branch?

Comment: `git checkout b fake_history $MERGE_BASE_SHA`, `git cherry-pick $shas_that_change_top/theModule`; git checkout master; git merge fake_history - you may have to fudge the cherry-picks if the commits contained other changes unrelated to that file.